# Why is my named routing is not working as expected In flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I created the named routes in my main but its not navigating.
Inside the mainbutton widget i'm passing the navigator it accepts three parameters all of them are required...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:texty/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:texty/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:texty/screens/registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:texty/screens/chat_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(FlashChat());

class FlashChat extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
      routes: {
        WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        ChatScreen.Id: (context) => ChatScreen(),
        LoginScreen.Id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        RegistrationScreen.Id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

my welcome screen ->

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:texty/widgets/mainbutton.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';
import 'registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';

  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.blueGrey, end: Colors.white)
        .animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: animation.value,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                    height: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                  text: ['Texxty '],
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 45.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            mainButton(
              title: 'Log In',
              colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.Id);
              },
            ),
            mainButton(
              title: 'Register',
              colour: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, RegistrationScreen.Id);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: its not routing

Answer (score 0):

try an other Option
instead of naming the pages

```
 Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
 );
```